# Nothing happens when I click on Button except when the EditText is empty

Tags: android, android-intent

am new in android and facing a problem in edit text view need your help. I just want to check EditText before going on next intent. If EditText is filled by at least 1 String then it will go to next intent. May be this is simple for you to implement but this is to difficult for me and I wasted half day on this. Is anyone here which can tell me where is the mistake in this code.

Thank you in advance

```
    package com.example.tricknearn;

    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;

public class Posttittle extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_posttittle);
            final EditText tittleInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tittleInput);
            Button postTittleButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.postTittleButton);
            postTittleButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    if (tittleInput.getText().length() == 0) {
                        tittleInput.setError("Please enter some text");
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        public void postTittleClick(View view) {


            EditText tittleInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tittleInput);
            Intent i = new Intent(this, Postdescription.class);

            if (tittleInput.getText().toString().equals("")){

            }else{

                startActivity(i);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do a null check if edittext is empty

Comment: null check ? you means to this ->

                if (tittleInput.getText().length() == 0) {
                        tittleInput.setError("Please enter some text");
                    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code instead...

```
public void postTittleClick(View view) {
        EditText tittleInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tittleInput);
        Intent i = new Intent(this, Postdescription.class);

        if (tittleInput.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
             // Here you can place code while edit text is empty
        }else{
            startActivity(i);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Cut the contents of "postTittleClick" method "onClickListener" then delete "postTittleClick" method ..

Comment: "postTittleClick" method is not being called .. when you click the button it does the code inside the "onClickListener" !

Comment: to avoid the exception in the "onClickListener" you may define "tittleInput" as final !

Answer (score 0):

Replace `if (tittleInput.getText().length() == 0)` with `if (tittleInput.getText().toString.equals(""))`

Comment: Oh sorry, my mistake. Do this: tittleInput.getText().toString().equals("")

Answer (score 0):

```
postTittleButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (tittleInput.getText().toString().isEmptry()) {
        //edittext is empty
        tittleInput.setError("Please enter some text");
    } else {
        //Edittext is not empty
        //start new Activity 
    }
  }
});
```

And remove `postTittleClick` method

Comment: i removed postTittleClick method and added your code, but it is giving exception in setOnClickListener  (postTittleButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() )